# What underlying semantic notions connect 'strēnuus' to stiffness and rigidity?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

> [[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strenuus#Etymology) :] From Proto-Indo-European **ster-* ‎(“stiff”). [...]

[Etymonline's entry for 'strenuous' (adj.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=strenuous) references [Etymonline's entry for 'stern' (adj.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=stern&allowed_in_frame=0) which states the same PIE root as above.

Why was 'strēnuus' assigned to the PIE root [**ster-*](http://www.utexas.edu/cola/centers/lrc/ielex/X/P1894.html)  ‎(“stiff”)? Univ. Texas states its  Semantic Field as 'Strong, Mighty, Powerful; Hard', but this still does not explain the Latin adjective's definitions of 'brisk, nimble, quick, prompt, active'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that *strenuus* means 'stiff' or 'rigid' in the sense of 'willing to stay by one's duty' or even 'stubborn in doing what one does'.
This kind of stiffness implies willingness and ability to do (hard) work.
From this point of view swiftness is a part of being *strenuus*, but 'quick' and such meanings seem secondary while the primary meaning is closer to 'devoted (to work)'.
While I have nothing to back this up with, this is how I have always thought about *strenuus* and it makes perfect sense with the proposed PIE root.